# How to see full history of comments to a question or an answer?

Tags: support, comments

Many questions and answers induce a healthy exchange of comments. As they get older, privileged mods tend to remove less constructive comments. Sometimes it creates a situation where a follow-up comment gets out-of-context.

Is there a way to see the full *comment* history?

Note - I am not talking about seeing *your* comment history, which can be done through your account dashboard, but rather the history of comments to a particular question or answer.

Comment: No because mods regularly delete comments with sensitive information with the expectation that nobody but other mods will be able to see deleted comments.

Comment: @Mysticial I believe 99% (probably much more) of the comments being deleted are deleted due to being too chatty or obsolete, not because of sensitive information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to see the full comment history?

No.

Edits to comments are preserved, so edit history does exist - however, this data is only available to moderators and staff.

Additionally, deleted comments (and their history) are only visible to moderators and staff.

Other users cannot see either deleted comments nor comment history.